# My loop is stuck in infinite loop I feel there are no errors please prove me wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

My loop is looping infinitely I am pretty sure it is not supposed to happen?

Here is my code:

```
def move(x, movie, g):
    global boo
    while boo:
        ij = 0
        for i in g:
            ij += 1
            if ij == movie and g[ij - 1] == "":
                g[ij - 1] = x
                boo = False
                break
            elif ij == 9 and movie == 9 and not g[ij - 1] == "":
                movie = input("Already occupied try again: ")
                boo = False
    return g
```

I am trying to make a function for a tic tac toe game.

Update here is the required details:

```
import md
g = ["", "", "o", "o", "", "", "", "", ""]
md.move("x", 4, g)
print(g)
```

**Gets stuck in the occupied part of the function**

Comment: Well, the if/else conditions might not be met and `boo` is never set to `False`. Add another `else` branch where you set `boo = False` and you should be fine.

Comment: remark: boo is a bad variable name as you can't see what it's used for.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. `boo` is not defined before being referenced. And what is `md`? Is that the module containing the `move` function above? Try moving it into the same module for the sake of example. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for other advice.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your stopping conditions are met:

```
ij == movie and g[ij - 1] == ""
```

when ij == movie (i.e. ij is 4), then g[ij-1] (i.e. g[3]) is not blank, it is "o"

```
ij == 9 and movie == 9 and not g[ij - 1] == ""
```

when ij is 9,  movie is not 9

So boo never gets set to False and the While loop repeats forever

Answer (score 0):

By debugging manually *boo* can’t be set to False.

Take a look carefully at your code:

When *ij* equals 4, *g[3]* equals **o**. Your first condition fails.

The second condition can’t succeed at any time because *movie* equals **4**. Whereas **9** is expected.

Regards.